# How to connect data to a devexpress blazor report?

Tags: devexpress, reporting, blazor

I have a .net core project which cotains a report viewer on a blazor page and I'm trying to bind it to a data source without success

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin: auto;">
    <DxDocumentViewer ReportUrl="PatientPending" Height="800px" Width="100%" @ref="Report">
        <DxDocumentViewerTabPanelSettings Width="180" />
    </DxDocumentViewer>
</div>
```

This is my data source

```
[DisplayName("PatientPending")]
    [HighlightedClass]
    public class PatientPendingDataSource {
        
        public PatientPendingDataSource() {
            
        }

        [HighlightedMember]
        public IEnumerable<Patient> GetData() {
            return new List<Patient> {
                new Patient {
                    Id = 5
                },
                new Patient {
                    Id = 6
                },
            };

        }
    }
```

The datasource of this report is typeof(PatientPendingDataSource) and the datamember to "GetData" I've set a breakpoint on the GetData method but it's never reached, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Document Viewer in Blazor apps obtain reports from [report storage](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/401677/web-reporting/blazor-reporting/blazor-quick-start#add-the-report-storage). Thus, you need to locate this report into storage and specify only the `ReportUrl` property. When binding this report to `IEnumerable<Patient>` make sure that you've checked the following entries in the data source wizard and then your method should be called at runtime:

1)
[image: Select a Member to Bind]

2)
[image]